# cann't install nokogiri 1.6.1 on Mac OS X 10.9 Maveriks

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, osx-mavericks

third day can't install nokogiri....Tried all instruction's from stack overflow and from official nokogiri page.Will be glad for any help,Thanx!!!!

> ruby -v 2.1
>
> rvm -v 1.25.18
>
> OS X 10.9.1
>
> > Xcode 5.0.2
>
> Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
>   Thread model: posix
>
> > brew list

```
apple-gcc42 grep        libksba     libxslt     pcre        sqlite
autoconf    libgpg-error    libtool     libyaml     pkg-config  wget
automake    libiconv    libxml2     openssl     readline    xz
```

> > Error in terminal

```
gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
/Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:211:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:211:in `which'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:198:in `block in tar_exe'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:197:in `each'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:197:in `find'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:197:in `tar_exe'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:242:in `extract_file'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:34:in `block in extract'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:32:in `extract'
    from /Users/bp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:106:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ideaprint_rails_4/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/bp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@ideaprint_rails_4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: show `xcode` version, please.

Comment: @Monk_Code,Xcode 5.0.2

Comment: you used this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296812/ruby-2-1-and-nokogiri-install-error)? looks like problem on `c` compiler

Comment: @Monk_Code,yes,my  [bash_profile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnon8sxthxurh77/bash_profile)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491145/nokogiri-fails-to-install-on-os-x a second option is worth trying in your case

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Btw, you need to have xcode installed first.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570890/702560

Comment: If I remember correctly, brew makes you do that when you install it, so this shouldn't be the solution if someone posts they already installed the brew packages needed for nokogiri.