# Bundle install failing on various gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I know this topic has been covered before and I have tried various solutions over the past 2 days but have yet to find a successful fix to this issue.

When I run bundle install on my new project get this error.

```
bundle install 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1) 
Using i18n (0.6.9) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.4) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activesupport (4.0.1) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.1) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.1) 
Using activemodel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord (4.0.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.2) 
Installing nokogiri (1.6.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp//ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp//ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
/Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:265:in `block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `chdir'
    from /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `execute'
    from /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:65:in `configure'
    from /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:108:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/conormacken/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I originally the issue was with the PG gem, I fear I may be making this issue worse rather than better. I am using brew, OSX 1.8.5 and ruby 2.0.0p247. I make the mistake of not tracking which issue I was trying to implement; apologies. Does anyone have any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? Someone seems to suggest installing latest version of grep via brew...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890808/install-nokogiri-1-6-1-under-ruby-2-0-0p353-rvm-based-installation-fails-osx

Comment: are you able to install libxml develoment package, in the same manner as pg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing up this issue, The issue was actually related to Xcode and it getting messed up somehow. Not a very informative solution but something to consider where debugging issues such a this.I just reinstalled Xcode and that did the trick.