# How to get Nokogiri to install on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation, nokogiri

This is what I get when I try to install Nokogiri on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:92:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.6.0/lib/mini_portile.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `<main>'
```

I checked the mkmf.log file and it says:

```
package configuration for libxml-2.0 is not found
package configuration for libxslt is not found
package configuration for libexslt is not found
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"gcc -E -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.     -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
4: 
5: #if LIBXML_VERSION < 20621
6: #error libxml2 is too old
7: #endif
/* end */
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251494/nokogiri-gem-installation-error) suggests installing with the `--use-system-libraries` flag.  For example: `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`

Comment: i've tried that, but been given similar results over and over again

Comment: A typical newbie problem on Debian-based systems is trying with `apt-get install libfoo` when you need `libfoo-dev` for the development headers. The base library package only contains the run-time binaries.