# gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, bundler

Building a new Rails app and getting a problem with nokogiri. Said to try `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1'` which fails with output below. I tried deleting Gemfile.lock and using the Gemfile from another app which has no problem—`bundle install` still fails. The original failure is `bundle install` which continues to work in other apps.

From console:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161008-60071-tmqi2l.rb extconf.rb
Ignoring byebug-6.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 6.0.2
Ignoring byebug-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 3.4.0
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:258:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:263:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:263:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:556:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/gem_make.out
```

mkmf.log:

```
"clang -o conftest -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"clang -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe    -Werror -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"clang -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future   -Werror -c conftest.c"
error: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

have_header: checking for iconv.h... -------------------- yes

"clang -E -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe   conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <iconv.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for gzdopen() in -lz... -------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -lz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <zlib.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))gzdopen; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_iconv?: checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... -------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-d46614.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-d46614.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <stdlib.h>
 4: #include <iconv.h>
 5: 
 6: int main(void)
 7: {
 8:     iconv_t cd = iconv_open("", "");
 9:     iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
10:     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
11: }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation -liconv -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <stdlib.h>
 4: #include <iconv.h>
 5: 
 6: int main(void)
 7: {
 8:     iconv_t cd = iconv_open("", "");
 9:     iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
10:     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
11: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

gem_make.out:

```
current directory: ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161008-60071-tmqi2l.rb extconf.rb
Ignoring byebug-6.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 6.0.2
Ignoring byebug-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 3.4.0
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:258:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:263:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:263:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:556:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: “To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here: [PATH]”

Comment: Edited original to include.

And I've tried:

  `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install`

and `brew install pkg-config` which was mentioned in one of the error statements. As expected said I already had it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nokogiri gem installation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251494/nokogiri-gem-installation-error)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I tried @the_basterd's recommendation. That didn't work, but the reference was good—thank you the_basterd. What worked from that reference was:

`brew install libxml2`

`bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2`

Reference: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1483

Later postings at that ref said that what I posted above "is strongly recommended against by the Nokogiri."

> `brew unlink xz; bundle install; brew link xz` **is preferred**.

Comment: You should “Accept” your own answer so people after you will know which answer solved the problem.

Comment: This worked for me installing 1.8.0 with ruby 2.4.1p111.  I had to create a Gemfile in my local directory with ruby gems source entry and gem 'nokogiri', but it worked beautifully. Delete the Gemfile afterwards.

Answer (score 52):

Run this first:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then rerun your bundle install

Reference: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1483

Comment: This is the solution which worked for me. I'm using MacOS Sierra

Comment: I don't know why the command-line tools weren't installed, but that was it.

Comment: And I don't know why the install takes sooooo long!

Answer (score 0):

You can also encounter the same error message if you've downloaded XCode Tools but haven't yet agreed to the license.

From Terminal, run:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Enter your admin password, space through the agreement and type `agree` to accept. Run `brew doctor` and if necessary, `brew update` and you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with nokogiri-1.6.8.1 while using `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to install directly into a project located within a Google Drive sync folder. The hangup seemed related to libxml2.

While reading through the GitHub issue referenced by @Greg and @the_basterd, I noticed that [someone was having trouble installing into a Box sync folder](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1483#issuecomment-234391896). Moving my project folder to another location worked.

Not sure what the underlying problem is when installing to a sync folder, but I'd be interested to learn if anyone had any thoughts.

Haven't tested this with Dropbox, but perhaps that would cause problems, too.