# How to install Nokogiri on Mac OS Sierra 10.12

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm having troubles installing Nokogiri (1.6.8.1) on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.

I tried using `brew install libxml2 libxslt` and then referencing the install directories using command line options but it didn't help.

Comment: If trying to install Nokogiri > v1.6.8.1 after installing Mac OS Sierra, I found that v1.7.1 will have problems if that's the first version being installed with that version of Ruby. Installing v1.6.8.1 then updating using `gem update nokogiri` through the intervening versions until v1.7.1 allowed me to get it installed. It's a hack but worked and once I had it installed I didn't feel like digging in more.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Open Xcode and, from the menu `XCode` -> `Preferences` update your Command Line Tools (Xcode 8.0).

Then do:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)"/usr/include/libxml2
bundle install
```

or just:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8.1 -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)"/usr/include/libxml2
```

Comment: The answer by NDan is simpler

Comment: New versions of Mac OS require Xcode to be updated, which invalidates the command-line tools, so they need to be reinstalled. Nokogiri is bundled with its own version of libxml2, which helps on many systems, but sometimes gem needs to be told where to find things. gem actually will do the right thing once Xcode is updated.

Comment: +1 Great! It works also if you have XCode 9.x. Here you don't need to update command line tools; if not updated just open XCode and it will take care of it.

Comment: this worked for me while the supposedly simpler answer mentioned in the comments didn't

Answer (score 126):

The more simple solution is to execute:

```
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
```

**Update**

For Mojave I'm using `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2' -- --use-system-libraries`

Comment: This worked for me. After updating to OS Sierra, I updated xcode and then nokogiri installed smoothly.

Comment: Working in 2017! Thanks 

Comment: You actually need to either open xcode and install updates or run code suggested here.

Comment: Thank you, it needs to burn in hell but at least this will likely fix it.

Answer (score 47):

Try install libxml2 first with Homebrew.

```
brew install libxml2
```

Then if installing with bundle

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries \
  --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
bundle install
```

If installing directly with gem

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries \
  --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
```

Comment: Worked for me too on High Sierra. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. You saved my day. Thanks. I am on High Sierra 10.13.3.

Answer (score 11):

This might be a duplicate of [gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937394/gem-install-nokogiri-v-1-6-8-1-fails/) ... latest accepted answer there was to do:

`brew unlink xz; bundle install; brew link xz`

Re-linking `xz` might not be necessary ... if for example you only have that dependency because of `the_silver_searcher` (which links directly against the non-symlinked library).

Answer (score 11):

```
gem update --system
xcode-select --install
brew unlink xz
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1'
brew link xz
```

If the above steps fail to fix the issue, what has also worked for me is running `brew doctor` and cleaning up any unbrewed header files.

Comment: This is what worked for me. For some reason 'bundle update' would fail. I had to install nokogiri as suggested in this answer.

Comment: I had previously installed Nokogiri just a few months ago, but changed Ruby versions and install of 1.8.0 was failing. I was able to install it via the unlink xz / gem isntall pattern (without gem update or xcode select)

Answer (score 10):

Similar to yuяi's answer and from Nokogiri's help:

```
brew unlink xz
gem install nokogiri
brew link xz
```

http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x

This worked for 1.7.0.1

Answer (score 1):

For Middleman

gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2' -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/

Answer (score 0):

If you have earlier installed nokogiri using bundler with `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries` this setting will still be there. If you then meanwhile have solved your Xcode setup (as suggested as the primary method of installation in the nokogiri installation) then you might wanna try removing that fra from bundler `bundle config --delete build.nokogiri` and try again doing `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

First install XCode from the app store

then run

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

this should work