# Rails server not loading gems after `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I didn't make any changes to my Rails app but when I went to run `rails s`, it's giving me this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/loofah-2.1.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/loofah-2.1.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:58:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:58:in `<module:Helpers>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
from /Users/jenyoung/Documents/Testing/Rails-Test/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/jenyoung/Documents/Testing/Rails-Test/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/jenyoung/Documents/Testing/Rails-Test/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/jenyoung/Documents/Testing/Rails-Test/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I have run `bundle install` which runs successfully but I'm still seeing the above error.

Could this be a configuration issue with my Rails and where it's looking for gems? If so, how can I set it to look for the gems in `./vendor/gems/ruby/2.4.0` instead?

I have also tried `gem install` on the various gems listed.

Here's where my Ruby and Rails are located:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

$ which -a ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails

$ which -a rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
/usr/bin/rails

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin16]

$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.6
```

I'm on OSX 10.12.6 - Sierra.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'hellosign-ruby-sdk'
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'nokogiri'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'httparty'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

So I also tried creating a brand new rails app and running rails s and it's also giving me a similar error starting like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Nokogiri on Mac OS Sierra 10.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038953/how-to-install-nokogiri-on-mac-os-sierra-10-12)

Comment: does `gem install nokogiri` work? did you follow this instructions? http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: Yes I've run `gem install nokogiri` and followed those directions as well and they run successfully

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails s` work?

Comment: `Could this be a configuration issue with my Rails and where it's looking for gems? If so, how can I set it to look for the gems in ./vendor/gems/ruby/2.4.0 instead?` this does not make sense. because you may use `ruby 2.4.0` for multiple apps so, it is better using `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/` path. This way, you do not install twice that gem for the same ruby version

Comment: maybe try doing a `bundle update` otherwise include your `gemfile` and if you have errors also the output of `bundle`

Comment: `bundle exec rails s` unfortunately doesn't work and i don't get any errors with `bundle` and i'll also add the gemfile to the original post

Comment: I think most people would recommend you use some sort of Ruby package manager (like RVM or rbenv) to contain your gem installs. Issues like this are likely to be avoided this way

Answer (score 0):

Remove the gem versions for all the gems giving you this error. E.g change gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' to gem 'uglifier' do this for all the gems generating an error. If it doesn't work, do not bundle install, just bundle(only applicable to old versions of bundler) the new version of bundler(I.e bundler pre--) bundles and installs whereas the old version bundles only.